# Adding placeholder images to WooCommerce shop page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add placeholder images to the shop page of a website, I want to have one default image I can set for any product with no images, instead of adding a placeholder image to each individual product.

I was successful in adding it to the single product page by using the plugin called "WooCommerce Customizer", but this does not add it on the products page.

The shop page where I would like to add placeholder images is:

http://www.orbetinternational.com/shop

I have tried creating a child functions.php file with this code

```
<?php

    add_action( 'init', 'custom_fix_thumbnail' );

    function custom_fix_thumbnail() {
    add_filter('woocommerce_placeholder_img_src', 'custom_woocommerce_placeholder_img_src');

    function custom_woocommerce_placeholder_img_src( $src ) {
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $uploads = untrailingslashit( $upload_dir['baseurl'] );
    $src = $uploads . '/2012/07/thumb1.jpg';

    return $src;
    }
}
```

I get the following error when I attempt this:

"Fatal error: Call to undefined function phpadd_action() in /home/orbetint/public_html/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child_Orbet/functions.php on line 1"

Comment: woocommerce already has a placeholder image for products without a thumbnail. How come those are not showing? Is that shop page using a custom template? If so, you need to fix that custom template. Also, if you need to replace the image with something else, check the documentation: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/change-the-placeholder-image/

Comment: I am using the Avada theme which apparently doesn't have a default image placeholder.
I have also tried the code on the page with a child functions file and I get an error every time... I will update the question with the code I am using and the error.

Comment: Looking at the error message, there doesn't seem to be any space between the php tag and the function add_action. Try adding an extra line break or a space?

Comment: I fixed that, same issue. I will update the question.

Comment: That's an awesome bit of code. Exactly what I was looking for. You should extend that and turn it into a plugin that people can define their own placeholder image. Let me know if you're not interested, I may even do it myself.

Comment: it is funny, once you know what you're looking for, it's easy to find. It's already been done! LOL https://shopplugins.com/custom-woocommerce-placeholder-image/

Answer (score 0):

If you are pasting the above code in functions.php, you must remove the initial call line,

```
<?php
```

Since it exists in the functions.php

Paste the code as is without the `<?php` and it will work normally.